# Oninput() not working on select

Tags: html

I am using this `oninput="setCustomValidity('')` on `input` tag perfectly but it not seem to be working in a `select` tag. Is this valid in `select` tag?.

```
<select class="dropdownlist" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please select Accused Name')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
```

Comment: In Chrome 64.0.3282.119, oninput works on select, but not on input[checkbox|radio|file].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply **No,** not valid for the `select`

The `oninput()` is useful if you want to detect when the contents of a `textarea`, `input:text`, `input:password` or `input:search` element have changed, because the `onchange` event on these elements fires when the element loses focus, not immediately after the modification.

So, use `onchange()` as an alternative for the same!

Hope this will help

Comment: In Chrome, Firefox, `oninput` event also fires when `select`, `input[checkbox|radio]` change. 'input' fires before 'change' event.

Comment: MDN states [that it *is* valid for <select>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) . onchange is also not the same as oninput. Onchange requires a blur of the input element.

Answer (score 5):

You can not use `oninput` attribute. you can use `onchange` attributes instead of `oninput`.

#### HTML

```
<select class="dropdownlist" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please select Accused Name')" onchange="setCustomValidity('')">
```

#### JavaScript

```
 function setCustomValidity()
 {
     var item= document.getElementByClassName('dropdownlist');
     var itemvalue= item.options[item.selectedIndex].text;
     ....
     ....
 }
```

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [all browsers support](https://caniuse.com/?search=oninput) `oninput` on the `<select>` element in 2023.

> The input event is fired when the user changes the value of an `<input>`
> element, `<select>` element, or `<textarea>` element. By contrast, the
> "change" event usually only fires after the form control has lost
> focus.